# Remote to remote block level replication

Tags: replication, block

I have to sync 2 iSCSI LUNs together at block-level (mandatory), asynchronous, only in the night, I found some tools to do it when Remote to Local or Local to Remote, but I cannot install anything on the LUNs' hosts, I have to do it remote to remote

Do you know such programs/distribs ?

Thanks

Mykeul

Answer (score 0):

Won't [DRBD](http://www.drbd.org/) go?

Comment: Hello, I cannot install anything on the remote hosts. Do you suggest I mount the 2 isci targets on a Linux box and then sync with DRBD from here ? I did not think of it, but I think I wont be able to replicate only at night. Thanks

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say `mount` I'd call it in ISCSI term `node login`, since there's no need in mounting at all.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the terms, I understand, but I could not stop it on day time, except stopping DRBD, would you know some appliance doing that ? I know Openfiler for example but I am not sur it can do remote to remote block level sync

Comment: Well, actually any synchronizer would need to track list of changed blocks, so I don't actually see how you're going to achieve that.

Comment: After a little bit of thinking .. drbd is replication between 2 hosts, and I only have 1, the one who see the 2 iscsi LUNs. Did I miss something ?